# Golang yaml unmarshal structure

Tags: go, yaml

I would need some help to handle configuration files in golang.
I renamed every fields and values for privacy (just saying)
I have this yaml configuration file :

```
Label1:
  field1: value1
  field2: value2
  field3: value3
  field4: value4
Label2:
  field1: value1
  field2: value2
  field3: value3
  field4: value4
Label3:
  field1: value1
  field2: value2
  field3: value3
  field4: value4
```

I'm using https://github.com/kylelemons/go-gypsy/tree/master/yaml to manually decode this yaml file into the structure below (manually walking the list of nodes). I don't have control over how many "Label" items will be on that file so I need a generic way of parsing it (and it is generic using the library mentioned above)

```
type Obj struct {
    Field1 string `yaml:"field1"`
    Field2 string `yaml:"field2"`
    Field3 string `yaml:"field3"`
    Field4 bool   `yaml:"field4"`
}

type ObjConfig struct {
    Objs map[string]Obj
}
```

I have several other configuration files, much simpler, which I'm able to decode using annotations such as :

```
type conf1 struct {
    Field1 int    `yaml:"field1"`
    Field2 string `yaml:"field2"`
}
```

I'm using the automatic yaml Unmarshal (through Viper framework) for these and it's working fine.

It wasn't a big deal mixing these 2 ways of handling configuration files until now. But now I need to retrieve the file from a spring config server that I did set up instead of having the files locally. I'm using this library to do so :
https://github.com/Piszmog/cloudconfigclient

It's working well for structures annotated with the `yaml:"fieldX"`, I'm able to deserialize it directly.
But for the first structure of course it's not working and I need a workaround. The library (cloudconfigclient) is using the classic yaml decoder so I can't write my own custom decoder. Looking at the library code it uses this code to deserialize the configuration file (with resp.Body being the yaml configuration file content) :

```
var dest interface{}
yaml.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(dest)
```

I'm able to change the configuraton file structure though, as long as I can get the same data in it. Maybe I could use something like

```
Labels:
  - Label1:
     field1: value1
     field2:value2
....
  - Label2:
     field1:value1
....
```

and use the yaml map handling from unmarshal ?

I'm obviously not experienced with golang, I'd love to get some help here.

To sum up, the question is how to decode the first yaml file using yaml.Unmarshal with the classic decoder (by either specific annotations that I don't know of, or changing the yaml structure itself).

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: Ye sorry lot of context but the question was not very clear, I've edited it and tried to sum up the question at the end.

Comment: did you try https://yaml.to-go.online/

Comment: I tried it just now, but it doesnt work because I need a generic way of parsing it (I dont have control over how many Label items are on the config file).

Comment: You can use Viper package to work with literally any kind of configuration files. That's what I use for my projects
https://github.com/spf13/viper

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by mapping it to a generic map[string]interface{} type

```
var configResponse map[string]interface{}
    err = configClient.GetFileFromBranch(BRANCH, CONF_DIR, CONF_FILE, &configResponse )
```

and then handling the cast myself into the structure

```
type ObjConfig struct {
    Objs map[string]Obj
}
```

Not the most easy to read nor resilient to error solution but it's working